# Complex Rails form with Nested Attributes (Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-attributes

I have a form, that is saving the main attribute, but not its nested attributes. I have dug into a lot of documents, and seem to be doing things correctly, but still get an error that my nested attributes "must exist".

My interview attributes are saving correctly to the database, but my logs show "Unpermitted parameters: student, parents"

My code is modified for brevity, but I will still try to be thorough enough to get some direction as to what might be going wrong ...

**Models** (which I include accepts_nested_attributes for :student, :parents)

:student is singular since it has a has_one relationship

:parents is plural since it has a has_many relationship

```
class Interview < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :student
  has_many :parents

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :student, :parents
end

class Student < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :interview
end

class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :interview
end
```

**Controller**

```
class InterviewsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @interviews = Interview.all
  end

  def show
    @interview = Interview.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @interview = Interview.new
    @interview.build_student
    2.times { @interview.parents.build }
  end

  def create
    @interview = Interview.new(interview_params)

    if @interview.save
      redirect_to @interview
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end



  private

    def interview_params
      params.require(:interview).permit(:date_today, :date_contact, :purpose_of_call, :problems_start_date, :cause, :violence, :running_away, :police_contact, :suicide, :self_harm, :other_info, :testing, :hospitalization, :medications, :school_problems, :teacher_relationships, :parent_goals, :notes,
      student_attributes: [:id, :name, :age, :height, :weight, :dob, :interview_id],
      parents_attributes: [:id, :name, :relationship, :parentage, :address, :phone_home, :phone_work, :phone_mobile, :phone_mobile, :email, :employer, :notes, :interview_id] )
    end

end
```

**Form** (important bits)

```
<%= form_for(@interview) do |f| %>

    <p class="inline">
      <%= f.label :date_today, 'Today\'s Date' %>
      <%= f.date_select(:date_today, :order => [:month, :day, :year], :start_year => 2000, :end_year => Date.today.year) %>
    </p>

    <p class="inline float_right">
      <%= f.label :date_contact, 'Initial Contact' %>
      <%= f.date_select(:date_contact, :order => [:month, :day, :year], :start_year => 2000, :end_year => Date.today.year) %>
    </p>

    <%= f.fields_for :student do |student_form| %>
      <p><%= student_form.text_field :name, placeholder: 'Name' %></p>

       <p class="inline">
         <%= student_form.label :age %>
         <%= student_form.text_field :age %>
       </p>

       <p class="inline">
         <%= student_form.label :height %>
         <%= student_form.text_field :height %>
       </p>

       <p class="inline">
         <%= student_form.label :weight %>
         <%= student_form.text_field :weight %>
       </p>

       ///// removed for brevity /////
      
    <% end %>

    <%= f.fields_for :parents do |parent_form| %>
      <%= render 'parents', :f => parent_form %>
    <% end %>
```

**Parent Partial**

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :name, 'Name' %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</p>

//// and more of the same /////
```

**Routes**

```
resources :interviews do
  resources :student
  resources :parents
end
```

The website form (at it's current state) can be found here: [www.compassconsultingwi.com/interviews/new](http://www.compassconsultingwi.com/interviews/new)

and the link to the github can be found here: https://github.com/plantoteachme/compassconsultingwi

**Params** returns this ..

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"nU4WM2RO5GJd36eaSLHMxhRQCOnY8EPjDhUdFBHlYGkcw6H7/Oc5y7kFx0HMU9nm5cc47ZZZBDW6oQ2QNF5yhA==", "interview"=>{"date_today(2i)"=>"11", "date_today(3i)"=>"16", "date_today(1i)"=>"2016", "date_contact(2i)"=>"10", "date_contact(3i)"=>"23", "date_contact(1i)"=>"2016", "student"=>{"name"=>"John", "age"=>"12", "height"=>"5 feet", "weight"=>"123 lbs", "dob(2i)"=>"3", "dob(3i)"=>"13", "dob(1i)"=>"2004", "strengths"=>"Great with his siblings", "weaknesses"=>"Lazy", "likes"=>"Food", "dislikes"=>"Chores", "medical_prolems"=>"ADD", "religous_training"=>"Catholic", "ethnic_issues"=>"none", "grade_level"=>"6"}, "parents"=>{"name"=>"Jamie", "relationship"=>"Mom", "parentage"=>"Strict", "address"=>"Miwaukee Wi", "phone_home"=>"555-1000", "phone_work"=>"555-1001", "phone_mobile"=>"555-1002", "email"=>"jj@jj.com", "employer"=>"Googleer", "notes"=>"PhD in Computer Science"}, "purpose_of_call"=>"Depression causing suicidal tendencies", "problems_start_date"=>"When we moved from Nigeria last year", "cause"=>"Relocating", "violence"=>"none", "running_away"=>"no", "police_contact"=>"no", "suicide"=>"Hasn't acted on it, but talks about it", "self_harm"=>"Minor bruising from \"sports\"", "other_info"=>"", "testing"=>"Yes, for ADD", "hospitalization"=>"no", "medications"=>"Regeline", "school_problems"=>"Getting bullied", "teacher_relationships"=>"Strained", "parent_goals"=>"Improve self awareness", "notes"=>"Our family was in Nigeria for mission work"}, "button"=>""}
```

Unpermitted parameters: student, parents

Comment: Have you tried separating the 'accepts_nested_attributes_for'? e.g. accepts_nested_attributes_for :student, accepts_nested_attributes_for :parents

Comment: I did, without success. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Do you still need `interview_id`? The association will be made automagically

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `cocoon` gem.

You can build a model object using `link_to_add_association` method of cocoon gem.

Also, you can remove object using `link_to_remove_association`

A fully working example here: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/wiki/ERB-examples